# Deleting occurrences of substring in string in singly linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a little problem out here.

I must to program a singly linked list stuff, and I hadn't got any problems since now. I stuck on the deletion by the occurrence of the substring given after the function call in authors name in linked list.

the program snippet:

```
void list_delete_element(kniha_t* inode)
{
    kniha_t *actualnode = inode;
    kniha_t *prevnode = NULL;
    kniha_t *tempnode = NULL;

    uchar_t needle[100];
    uchar_t haystack[100];
    ushort_t occur = 0;

    scanf("%s", &needle);
    lower_string(needle);
    while(actualnode != NULL)
    {
        copy_string(haystack, actualnode->autori);
        lower_string(haystack);
        if(search_string(haystack, needle))
        {
            occur++;
            if ( NULL != prevnode)
            {
                prevnode->next = actualnode->next;
            }
            else
            {
                inode = actualnode->next;
            }
            tempnode = actualnode;
            actualnode = actualnode->next;
            free(tempnode);
            tempnode = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            prevnode = actualnode;
            actualnode = actualnode->next;
        }
    }
    printf("Deleted sa %hu nodes\n", occur);
}
```

and the stuff I must load in it, ignoring the ---:
http://pastebin.com/NPvEr3y6
the problem is, that works ( :D )...until I sweep all the occurrences. 

Example:
When I type in pra, it must delete all the nodes that contains "pra". It works like a charm...but when I type only "p", it tells me, that all the X occurrences were freed, but they stay in the buffer somewhere, because I can print the whole list out again!

I will be very thankful, who can give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list_delete_element` should take `kniha_t**` so that you can delete the head node and prune linked list. With current code, you delete the node, but other functions doesn't know that because `inode` is not changed.

You you can update your code as

```
void list_delete_element(kniha_t* *inode)
{
    kniha_t *actualnode = *inode;
    ...
        if ( NULL != prevnode)
        {
            prevnode->next = actualnode->next;
        }
        else
        {
            *inode = actualnode->next;
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this statement:

```
 tempnode = NULL;
```

does nothing, actually, since you never do anything with `tempnode` besides assignment and immediately freeing.

Comment: thank you, removed, but that have no impact on the behaviour of the deleting function :/

Comment: no prob dude ;) You still showed me that line is useless. thank you too